# How to take head(n) and tail(n) in one groupby with polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Here is a sample dataframe, I want to get head(n) rows and tail(n) rows in everyday which is a `groupby("date").agg()` with polars. I know it could use two groupby to get head and tail part and then concat them. Is there some trick to do this in one groupby or with_columns or filter?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a general way to get the `head(n)` and `tail(n)` per group into a final DataFrame, without `concat` shenanigans, and using a trivial df as an example.

It uses `filter` to take out the middle rows over each group, with appropriate calculations being done with `cumcount` and `count`, with `over` doing the groupby-aggregations in place:

```py
N = 50

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": [1] * N + [2] * N,
        "value": range(1, 2 * N + 1),
    }
)

n = 2
df.filter(
    ~pl.col('group')
    .cumcount()
    .over('group')
    .is_between(n, pl.col('group').count().over('group') - n, closed='left')
)
```

```py
shape: (8, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1     │
│ 1     ┆ 2     │
│ 1     ┆ 49    │
│ 1     ┆ 50    │
│ 2     ┆ 51    │
│ 2     ┆ 52    │
│ 2     ┆ 99    │
│ 2     ┆ 100   │
└───────┴───────┘
```

You can adjust `n` and see that it works for all non-negative `n`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this wonderful solution. I add some code to make sure it could get same length head and tail part no matter what n input.

Comment: ```df.filter(~pl.col('group').cumcount().over('group').is_between(pl.min_horizontal(n, (pl.col('group').count().over('group')/2).floor()), pl.col('group').count().over('group') - pl.min_horizontal(n, (pl.col('group').count().over('group')/2).floor()), closed='left'))```

Comment: Is there any possible that make the value of `head(n)` as 1 and `tail(n)` as -1 in this case? @Wayoshi

Comment: I don't think negative indices makes sense for head/tail? Not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for my words, the `value` series is sorted in every group, and the final target is that I want to turn the `value.head(n)` into -1 and  `value.tail(n)` into +1 as a signal in a `over("group")` view. The middle part is no use. -1 and +1 are not index but the final value which are selected by head and tail

Answer (score 1):

[@Wayoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21191420/wayoshi) has already submitted an answer which you've accepted, however, there's some ambiguity in the format which you'd like the results to be in. So here I submit a couple of different solution forms to the same problem, inspired by @Wayoshi's example data, which might be useful to others

Creating example data:

```py
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

groups = 4
group_size = 10
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": np.repeat(range(groups), group_size),
        "value_a": range(groups * group_size),
        "value_b": range(0, groups * group_size ** 2, group_size),
    }
)
df
# shape: (40, 3)
# ┌───────┬─────────┬─────────┐
# │ group ┆ value_a ┆ value_b │
# │ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
# │ i64   ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
# ╞═══════╪═════════╪═════════╡
# │ 0     ┆ 0       ┆ 0       │
# │ 0     ┆ 1       ┆ 10      │
# │ 0     ┆ 2       ┆ 20      │
# │ 0     ┆ 3       ┆ 30      │
# │ …     ┆ …       ┆ …       │
# │ 3     ┆ 36      ┆ 360     │
# │ 3     ┆ 37      ┆ 370     │
# │ 3     ┆ 38      ┆ 380     │
# │ 3     ┆ 39      ┆ 390     │
# └───────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

To create separate `head` and `tail` columns for each group, and each value, where each head and tail is a list of values:

```py
n = 3
(
    df
    .groupby("group", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.col("*").head(n).suffix("_head"),
        pl.col("*").tail(n).suffix("_tail"),
    )
)
# shape: (4, 5)
# ┌───────┬──────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────────┐
# │ group ┆ value_a_head ┆ value_b_head    ┆ value_a_tail ┆ value_b_tail    │
# │ ---   ┆ ---          ┆ ---             ┆ ---          ┆ ---             │
# │ i64   ┆ list[i64]    ┆ list[i64]       ┆ list[i64]    ┆ list[i64]       │
# ╞═══════╪══════════════╪═════════════════╪══════════════╪═════════════════╡
# │ 0     ┆ [0, 1, 2]    ┆ [0, 10, 20]     ┆ [7, 8, 9]    ┆ [70, 80, 90]    │
# │ 1     ┆ [10, 11, 12] ┆ [100, 110, 120] ┆ [17, 18, 19] ┆ [170, 180, 190] │
# │ 2     ┆ [20, 21, 22] ┆ [200, 210, 220] ┆ [27, 28, 29] ┆ [270, 280, 290] │
# │ 3     ┆ [30, 31, 32] ┆ [300, 310, 320] ┆ [37, 38, 39] ┆ [370, 380, 390] │
# └───────┴──────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

To create separate `head` and `tail` columns for each group, and each value,
where each head and tail is "un-listed" (is this format useful? I'm not
sure...)

```py
n = 3
(
    df
    .groupby("group", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.col("*").head(n).suffix("_head"),
        pl.col("*").tail(n).suffix("_tail"),
    )
    .explode(pl.exclude("group"))
)
# shape: (12, 5)
# ┌───────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
# │ group ┆ value_a_head ┆ value_b_head ┆ value_a_tail ┆ value_b_tail │
# │ ---   ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
# │ i64   ┆ i64          ┆ i64          ┆ i64          ┆ i64          │
# ╞═══════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
# │ 0     ┆ 0            ┆ 0            ┆ 7            ┆ 70           │
# │ 0     ┆ 1            ┆ 10           ┆ 8            ┆ 80           │
# │ 0     ┆ 2            ┆ 20           ┆ 9            ┆ 90           │
# │ 1     ┆ 10           ┆ 100          ┆ 17           ┆ 170          │
# │ …     ┆ …            ┆ …            ┆ …            ┆ …            │
# │ 2     ┆ 22           ┆ 220          ┆ 29           ┆ 290          │
# │ 3     ┆ 30           ┆ 300          ┆ 37           ┆ 370          │
# │ 3     ┆ 31           ┆ 310          ┆ 38           ┆ 380          │
# │ 3     ┆ 32           ┆ 320          ┆ 39           ┆ 390          │
# └───────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

To create a combined `head_tail` column for each group, where each head and tail is a list of values (again, is the format "useful"? probably not... but that's for someone else to decide):

```py
n = 3
(
    df
    .groupby("group", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.col("*").head(n).append(pl.col("*").tail(n)).suffix("_head_tail"),
     )
)
# shape: (4, 3)
# ┌───────┬───────────────────┬───────────────────┐
# │ group ┆ value_a_head_tail ┆ value_b_head_tail │
# │ ---   ┆ ---               ┆ ---               │
# │ i64   ┆ list[i64]         ┆ list[i64]         │
# ╞═══════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
# │ 0     ┆ [0, 1, … 9]       ┆ [0, 10, … 90]     │
# │ 1     ┆ [10, 11, … 19]    ┆ [100, 110, … 190] │
# │ 2     ┆ [20, 21, … 29]    ┆ [200, 210, … 290] │
# │ 3     ┆ [30, 31, … 39]    ┆ [300, 310, … 390] │
# └───────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

I'm not convinced that the operation would ever be useful, but who am I to say. If you wanted to head and tail all your value columns into a single column, stored as a list:

```py
n = 3
(
    df
    .groupby("group", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.concat([pl.exclude("group").head(n), pl.exclude("group").tail(n)]).alias("all_head_tail")
    )
)
# shape: (4, 2)
# ┌───────┬─────────────────┐
# │ group ┆ all_head_tail   │
# │ ---   ┆ ---             │
# │ i64   ┆ list[i64]       │
# ╞═══════╪═════════════════╡
# │ 0     ┆ [0, 1, … 90]    │
# │ 1     ┆ [10, 11, … 190] │
# │ 2     ┆ [20, 21, … 290] │
# │ 3     ┆ [30, 31, … 390] │
# └───────┴─────────────────┘
```

And finally, if you wanted to head and tail all your value columns into a single
column, and unlist the values (the format which Wayoshi offered), an
alternative way to achieve this would be:

```py
n = 3
(
    df
    .groupby("group", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.concat([pl.exclude("group").head(n), pl.exclude("group").tail(n)]).alias("all_head_tail")
    )
    .explode("all_head_tail")
)
# shape: (48, 2)
# ┌───────┬───────────────┐
# │ group ┆ all_head_tail │
# │ ---   ┆ ---           │
# │ i64   ┆ i64           │
# ╞═══════╪═══════════════╡
# │ 0     ┆ 0             │
# │ 0     ┆ 1             │
# │ 0     ┆ 2             │
# │ 0     ┆ 0             │
# │ …     ┆ …             │
# │ 3     ┆ 39            │
# │ 3     ┆ 370           │
# │ 3     ┆ 380           │
# │ 3     ┆ 390           │
# └───────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for this clear solution, it seems `append` works well for me.